# How to pass data from a FlatList to a BottomSheet in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I used BottomSheet from https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/

Say I have a FlatList that renders buttons, how can I make it that when a certain button is pressed, the BottomSheet will open and will contain whatever data I passed in it? Say, the `title` data.

Here's my code:

```
import { BottomSheetModal, BottomSheetModalProvider, BottomSheetScrollView } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

import { useRef, useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react"

const DATA = [
    {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'John Doe',
    },
    {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'John Smith',
    },
    {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'John Lennon',
    },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
    <AppButton title={title} style={{ marginVertical: 10 }} />
);

const App = () => {

    // ref
    const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef(null);

    // variables
    const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);

    // callbacks

    const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
        bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
    }, []);

    const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index) => {
        console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
    }, []);

    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <FlatList
                    data={DATA}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
                />
            </View>

            <BottomSheetModalProvider>
                <BottomSheetModal
                    ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
                    index={0}
                    snapPoints={snapPoints}
                    enablePanDownToClose
                    onChange={handleSheetChanges}
                >
                    <BottomSheetScrollView>

                    </BottomSheetScrollView>
                </BottomSheetModal>
            </BottomSheetModalProvider>
    )
}
```

I only copied much of the code for the BottomSheet from the docs and I have no knowledge yet about usecallback and useref so if what I want to happen needs those two, kindly indicate it :)

If im not using a list I managed to do it but had to create many copies of bottom sheet and refs and i know that is not very efficient

Refer to the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Do you use any state management tool? Like Redux?

Comment: No, I do not, its all react native

Comment: well I suggest you to check this :)
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure